# In Ruby 1.9.3, a vector can't be multiplied by another vector?

Tags: ruby, vector

I am implementing basic machine learning algorithm in Ruby, 1.9.3.

I try to use class Matrix and Vector for the arithmetics. But when I try to multiply a vector by another vector, it says 
"ExceptionForMatrix::ErrOperationNotDefined: Operation(*) can't be defined: Vector op Vector".

But the doc of Ruby, 1.9,3 [says](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-2A):

> *(x) Multiplies the vector by x, where x is a number or another vector.

My code and output is here:

```
> a = Vector[1,2,3]
=> Vector[1, 2, 3]
> b = Vector[1,2,3]
=> Vector[1, 2, 3]
> a * b
ExceptionForMatrix::ErrOperationNotDefined: Operation(*) can't be defined: Vector op Vector
```

Answer (score 4):

Although the documentation clearly states that you can multiply a vector by another vector, it's nonsensical, and, as zisasign points out, the implementation doesn't permit it.

However, you can turn either vector into a one-row matrix using the `covector` method, which you can then multiply to give a meaningful calculation:

```
a = Vector[1, 2, 3]
b = Vector[10, 100, 1000]

a.covector * b
# => Vector[3210]

a * b.covector
# => Matrix[[10, 100, 1000], [20, 200, 2000], [30, 300, 3000]]
```

Comment: From your examples, I'd guess that `Vector` is in fact a column-vector/one-column matrix whereas the result of `covector` is a row-vector/one-row matrix.  No?

Comment: yeah, I found vector can be multiplied with Matrix, too.

Comment: @undur_gongor method covector return a matrix.

Comment: @zisasign What this looks like to me is the authors of the `matrix` library just defined a covector = row-vector to be a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is wrong. When you look at the code linked in the doc, there is

```
def *(x)
  case x
  when Numeric
    els = @elements.collect{|e| e * x}
    Vector.elements(els, false)
  when Matrix
    Matrix.column_vector(self) * x
  when Vector
    Vector.Raise ErrOperationNotDefined, "*", self.class, x.class
  else
    apply_through_coercion(x, __method__)
  end
end
```

Multiplying (as in matrix-multiplication) a (column-)vector by a (column-)vector does not make sense, anyway. Maybe you want `inner_product`?

Comment: I was about to write literally the same thing, +1 :)

Comment: I think a row vector should be multiplied with a column vector, vice versa. But Ruby says 'No'.

Comment: @zisasign You're not wrong. Covector in `require(matrix)` is synonymous with "row vector" as you used the term.